# Ksoap downloaded as zip causes java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, ksoap2

I have downloaded ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.4-jar-with-dependencies which
was downloaded as zip file.

When I add it to my project I get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.
How can I add It as a jar file?

10x & have a good weekend

Answer (score 1):

I really recommend that you look into maven, and use maven to get ksoap2. It's a bit of work getting maven set up, but well worth it!

Answer (score 0):

Have you unzipped it into some directory?  If so, RightClick on project name, click properties, Java Build Path, Add External Jar assuming you are using Eclipse

Comment: If I unzip the file, I get 2 directories: "META-INF" and "org", but no jar file. I probably missed something about d/l these files.

Answer (score 0):

java -jar `jarfilename` ......  (this is used when your 'executable' is in the jarfile

but what you probably want is for the jarfile to be in your classpath

java -classpath `jarfilename` ......

```
- or -
```

java -cp `jarfilename`

Comment: Tried It, didn`t work. Seems I`m missing something very basic here.

Comment: @Udi I, show the import and calling lines of your .java file as well as the full error

Answer (score 0):

change extension from zip to jar
you downloaded the file and changed the extension when you "saved to" location

Answer (score 0):

Follow the download instruction on the wiki and it will work. Really follow then though.
Right click on View Raw File. More at

http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/HowToUse?tm=2

Answer (score 0):

Turns out external jars such as

ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar

to be put under /libs folder so Eclipse ADT automatically adds your jars to the buildpath of your application. It was a buildpath missing defined class error after all.. I hope this will help you, too!

[Solved here!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853113/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-ksoap2-serialization-soapobject)