# java.lang.noclassdeffounderror: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject

Tags: android, ksoap2

I got this no class def error: `org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject` error ever since I have updated Eclipse ADT Plug in and SDK Manager. I was using `ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar` as external library for KSOAP. I thought that may be deprecated so i also added 2.6.2 version from here:http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/source/browse/m2-repo/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly/2.6.2/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar

I still get the error. I have also search for it through the site but nothing helped.

Please help.

Code:

```
SoapServis servis = new SoapServis(SoapServis.KULLANICI_KONTROL);
```

where constructor is:

```
public SoapServis(String metodAdi) {
    this.METHOD_NAME = metodAdi;
    this.Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Turns out external jars such as

> ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar

to be put under `/libs` folder so Eclipse ADT **automatically** adds your jars to the buildpath of your application. It was a buildpath missing defined class error after all.. I hope this will help you, too!

Mustafa

Answer (score 17):

Go to **Properties -> Java Build Path**

Add ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar as external jar

Go to the Order and Export tab on the same popup window

Check the box against the newly added jar

(see: [NoClassDefFoundError - Eclipse and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247998/noclassdeffounderror-eclipse-and-android))

Answer (score 4):

What I did:

1. Download ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.5-jar-with-dependencies, if you see it comes with zip extension. Change it to jar extension.
2. Copy the jar file to libs folder on your project.
3. Rebuild your project.

Comment: :) this the only simple one worked for me ; i had gcm.jar google cloud messaging system  thanks  :) withouth build java path etc things