# Android eclipse jar file class not found at run time

Tags: android, eclipse

I have extracted a jar file and then zipped the classes to jar again. The jar is then added to libs folder of my android project.The problem is the class is found at compile time.But at run time it says one class in the jar is not found.

```
Could not find class 'org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope', referenced from 
method com.globaleyeventures.eyexam.Data.SOAPConnection.SOAPConnection.SOAPConnect
```

Comment: Post Your error code.

Comment: please check this post,It may be helpful, 
                 http://stackoverflow.com/a/9858533/1476699

Answer (score 1):

Go to the properties of the project by right clicking on the project. Then go to Java build path and then Order and Export tab. See if the jar included is checked. If not then check it and clean your project again and run.

Comment: It is there in the build path, that is why it is getting at compile time.

Comment: I also got the same problem by putting jar in the libs folder. It was getting compiled but not able to find the class during the runtime. Turned out the corresponding libraries were not marked checked in the order and export tab.